# Javascript World Clock Only Shows in Table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display times from a few different cities around the world, and I have searched and Google'd and even used the answer found here: [World Clock API in php or in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486198/world-clock-api-in-php-or-in-javascript), but the clocks will only display in a table. I used this website's tutorial: http://www.proglogic.com/code/javascript/time/worldclock.php (among others. This one seemed the most straight forward.).

I am trying to get it to display in my nav bar, similar to this page: https://www.blackcard.com/, so a table does not seem like the way to go. Of course, I may be wrong.

Also, I am using Bootstrap, if that matters at all.

Let me know if you all have any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this

you will need these two files:

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js
http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js

With moment.js, you could do the below:

**html:**

```
<div id="myCoolNavBarr"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
//create a "moment" object from the current date/time
//use the timezone functionality to to set the timezone of the "moment"
//specify the format to display just the time 
var newYork = moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("h:mm: A");
var london = moment.tz("Europe/London").format("h:mm: A");
var hongKong = moment.tz("Asia/Hong_Kong").format("h:mm: A"); 
var tokyo = moment.tz("Asia/Tokyo").format("h:mm: A");


//put them to use 
$("#myCoolNavBarr").append("NY  "+newYork+ " --- LDN  " +london+ " --- HK  " +hongKong+ " --- TYO  " +tokyo)
```

Here is a working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d32s5r2c/2/)

Comment: Can I use the two files as a CDN, or do I need to download them?