# Handling date across timezones in web-application in Mongo and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am working on an intranet web application. This application is used across US, Europe and Asia.

From a datepicker widget in the user's browser, I capture the date and then pass it on to my application which is running off a server in the US.

```
new Date().toISOString();
```

I am using the JavaScript Date Object and converting the date to UTC format and then passing it to the server for storage in Mongo DB.

The storage works fine.

However I am next suppose to send a email reminder to users in Europe and Asia an hour before the captured time.

I am completely confused on how this should be performed.

The dates in Mongo are in UTC format. How do I retrieve all documents from the database such that their time is close to one hour away ( so that I can emit an event which will fire off reminder emails).

What kind of query does one write for this ?

Comment: You can use `new Date()` to create a Date object, and UTC methods to get the current UTC time. Then construct a query to get the appropriate entries from the database. So is this a javascript or SQL question?

Comment: How are you storing the dates in MongoDB? I am worried you are storing them as strings because you are using `.toISOString()`. Store the dates as datetimes. To handle time in your application, just work in UTC always. When you get a time, convert to UTC. When you are displaying a local time, convert from UTC. Inside your app and the database, just have everything in UTC - that should minimize your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to  write the actual Query for Mongo DB but maybe this will help.

You could:

- Use a CRON job to run a Query every hour.
- When the Query runs, get all objects that need a reminder today.
- The objects will need to have the user's timezone stored within them.
- Use Moment.js and it's timezone component to convert the captured time to the user's time zone.
- If the captured time is within the next hour, send the email.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920649/javascript-world-clock-only-shows-in-table/26921514#26921514) shows how to use moment.js and the timezone component

Comment: The OP has all times stored as UTC, getting the current UTC time on the server is trivial, there is no requirement to consider timezone at all. The question is more about how to format the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your seeking but two options.

you can retrieve using a > && <=  on a crontab basis as suggested.

```
var now =  ISODate("2014-01-16T01:00:00.000Z");
var houragp = now - 1hr
db.collection.find({ "yourdate" : { $gt : hourago , $lte : now }  })
```

alternatively look at [this aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) that cuts down a date into components. Note that the dollarsign for the key $yourdate is an aggregate idiom.

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
         {
           year: { $year: "$yourdate" },
           month: { $month: "$yourdate" },
           day: { $dayOfMonth: "$yourdate" },
           hour: { $hour: "$yourdate" },
           minutes: { $minute: "$yourdate" },
           seconds: { $second: "$yourdate" },
           milliseconds: { $millisecond: "$yourdate" },
           dayOfYear: { $dayOfYear: "$yourdate" },
           dayOfWeek: { $dayOfWeek: "$yourdate" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Your case may simply need.

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
         {
           hour: { $hour: "$yourdate" },
         }
     }
   ]
)
```