# how to set offset time for london time in world clock webpart

Tags: jquery, time

I have a  world clock code for ("India","Malaysia","Qatar","Indonesia"). I need to add London time. I don't know how time is calculated for malaysia,qatar and indonesia.

```
function showLocalTime(container, servermode, offsetMinutes,  displayversion) 
{
  if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementById(container))       
  return;
  this.container = document.getElementById(container);
  this.displayversion = displayversion;
  var servertimestring = '<%=DateTime.Now%>';
  this.localtime = this.serverdate = new Date(servertimestring);
  this.localtime.setTime(this.serverdate.getTime() + offsetMinutes  60    1000); //add user offset to server time
  this.updateTime();
  this.updateContainer();
 }

<script type="text/javascript">
new showLocalTime("Malaysia", "server-asp", 0, "short");
new showLocalTime("Qatar", "server-asp", -300, "short");
new showLocalTime("India", "server-asp", -150, "short");
new showLocalTime("Indonesia", "server-asp", 60, "short");
</script>
```

above code work fine

qatar = -300 , india  = -150 , indonesia = 60 what it represent. then how i need to add value for London?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920649/javascript-world-clock-only-shows-in-table/26921514#26921514

Comment: Thank u DelightedDD but i need to use above code only i need to add london time only.